# How to use a set algebra operation in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, algebra, relational-algebra

I need to find the distinct drinkers who like either BEER or RED WINE. However, the query must be implemented with a set algebra operation.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DRINKER 
FROM LIKES 
WHERE DRINK = 'BEER' OR 'RED WINE';
```

This is not using a set algebra operation though. I'm really new to SQL so any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the table I'm getting data from:

```
CREATE TABLE LIKES( /* Drinkers like drinks */
DRINKER     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drinker name */
DRINK       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   /* Drink name   */
RATING      DECIMAL(1)  NOT NULL,   /* Rating of the drink  */
    CONSTRAINT LIKES_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(DRINKER, DRINK),
    CONSTRAINT LIKES_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY(DRINK) REFERENCES ALLDRINKS(DRINK),
    CONSTRAINT LIKES_DKEY2 FOREIGN KEY(DRINKER) REFERENCES DRINKERS(DRINKER));
```

As well as the table 'DRINKERS':

```
CREATE TABLE DRINKERS ( /* All drinkers */
DRINKER VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT DRINKERS_PKEY PRIMARY KEY (DRINKER));
```

INSERT statements:

```
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('TOM', 'BEER', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JANUSZ', 'VODKA', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JANUSZ', 'RUM', 5);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JANUSZ', 'BEER', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JANUSZ', 'CHAMPAGNE', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JANUSZ', 'RED WINE', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JANUSZ', 'WHITE WINE', 5);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JANUSZ', 'PORT', 5);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('PETER', 'CHAMPAGNE', 4);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('PETER', 'COGNAC', 3);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('PETER', 'RUM', 3);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('PETER', 'WHISKY', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('MARY', 'CHAMPAGNE', 5);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('MARY', 'VODKA', 1);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('MARY', 'COGNAC', 4);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JOHN', 'CHAMPAGNE', 4);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JOHN', 'VODKA', 2);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JOHN', 'RUM', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JOHN', 'WHISKY', 1);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JOHN', 'BEER', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JAMES', 'CHAMPAGNE', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JAMES', 'COGNAC', 5);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('JAMES', 'RUM', 4);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('SERGIEY', 'VODKA', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('SERGIEY', 'RUM', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('SERGIEY', 'CHAMPAGNE', 3);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('CLAUDE', 'CHAMPAGNE', 6);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('CLAUDE', 'WHITE WINE', 5);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('CLAUDE', 'COGNAC', 4);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('CLAUDE', 'WHISKY', 3);
INSERT INTO LIKES VALUES('CLAUDE', 'RED WINE', 6);
```

Desired output:

```
DRINKER

JANUSZ
JOHN
TOM
```

Comment: Sample data ( INSERT statements) and desired result would be useful

Comment: [DRINK IN ('BEER', 'RED WINE')](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/expressions.html), I'm not sure if that constitutes set algebra however.

Comment: @Strawberry updated with insert statements and desired output

Comment: There seem to a bunch of similar questions around; are you all doing the same assignment?

Comment: What do you mean, "set algebra"? Do you mean [tag:relational-algebra?] SQL tables contain bags of rows, not sets of rows. Were you told that certain SQL operators are its "set algebra" operators? Why is it that "the query must be implemented with a set algebra operation" & what does "set algebra operation" mean here exactly? Please give the exact wording of your assignment, it's not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UNION` is a set algebra operation supported by MySQL in two forms: [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) and `UNION ALL`. The former returns only distinct values from the set, the latter all values (so with your sample data, would return `JANUSZ` twice since they like `BEER` and `RED WINE`). So, a set algebra like query to find drinkers who like `BEER` or `RED WINE` would be:

```
SELECT DRINKER
FROM LIKES
WHERE DRINK = 'BEER'
UNION
SELECT DRINKER 
FROM LIKES 
WHERE DRINK = 'RED WINE'
```

Output for your sample data:

```
DRINKER
TOM
JANUSZ
JOHN
CLAUDE
```

(Note that CLAUDE also likes RED WINE)

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/skuAPs59VvbUyFZteZRrKa/0)

You can add an `ORDER BY` clause to a `UNION` to order the final result. Without one, the order of results is not guaranteed. For example to sort alphabetically:

```
SELECT DRINKER
FROM LIKES
WHERE DRINK = 'BEER'
UNION
SELECT DRINKER 
FROM LIKES 
WHERE DRINK = 'RED WINE'
ORDER BY DRINKER
```

Output:

```
DRINKER
CLAUDE
JANUSZ
JOHN
TOM
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/skuAPs59VvbUyFZteZRrKa/1)

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, Set Algebra operations are UNION, INTERSECT and EXCEPT. For your needs, I think UNION would be the best choice.

Since you did not specify what rating constitutes whether someone likes a drink or not, for this query we'll assume <=5 means they don't like it and >5 means they do like it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DRINKER
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DRINKER
      FROM LIKES
      WHERE DRINK="BEER"
      AND RATING>5
      UNION
      SELECT DISTINCT DRINKER
      FROM LIKES
      WHERE DRINK="RED WINE"
      AND RATING>5);
```

Using the assumption of "Likes" is a rating >5, you would get this output from your chosen INSERT statemements:

```
CLAUDE
JANUSZ
JOHN
TOM
```

You can read more about Set operations here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)

Comment: Note that MySQL doesn't support INTERSECT or EXCEPT.

Comment: @EricMcCormick . . . You have way more `DISTINCT`s in this query than necessary.